# Salvar $scope da página com angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tenho uma tela onde algumas funcionalidade são feitas via ajax na página, então o usuário pode efetuar filtros, etc;

Ao verificar o resultado que ele deseja, o mesmo pode clicar em um link que irá redirecionar ele para uma nova página, porém se ele clicar no back do browser ele irá retornar para página anterior e irá perder os filtros que ele fez.

Preciso armazenar a variável `vm`(`$scope-this`) para que ao voltar eu pegue essa variável e sete novamente na variável `vm`, porém não está dando certo pois eu armazeno ela em um hidden.

Existe alguma outra coisa que posso tentar?

Comment: Já pensou em usar LocalStorage? O Angular tem uma library para isso.

Comment: Ou então se você usar esses argumentos de filtro diretamente na URL também pode manter o filtro ao voltar a página

Answer (score 1):

Como já falaram vc pode usar o `SessionStorage` ou `LocalStorage`. O Angular já tem uma biblioteca que facilita o uso dos dois: [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage)

Tudo que você precisa fazer é salvar seu filtro em um dos dois e depois recupera-lo onde deseja. Exemplo:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngStorage']);

function MyCtrl($scope, $localStorage) {
    //Recupera o objeto que está no localStorage
    $scope.myFilter = $localStorage.filter;
    console.log($scope.myFilter);
  
    $scope.filtrate = function(data) {
        //Salva o objeto no localStorage
        $localStorage.filter = data;
        console.log($localStorage.filter);
    };
  
    $scope.clearStorage = function(){
      //Limpa o localStorage de nome filter
      delete $localStorage.filter;
      console.log($localStorage.filter);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ngStorage/0.3.11/ngStorage.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" placeholder="Name"/>
 <input type="text" ng-model="user.age" placeholder="Age"/>
 <button ng-click="filtrate(user)">Filter</button>
 <button ng-click="clearStorage()">Clear Storage</button>
</div>
```

Como `WebStorage` não é suportada no *code snippet* segue o [exemplo no jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sinkz/Lvc0u55v/8281/)

Answer (score -1):

Tem varios metodos de se fazer isso, particularmente eu prefiro usar [services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) sem um pouco de codigo fica um pouco complicado ajudar mais. Dependendo da situação pode colocar toda a logica dentro do service.

Nesse caso que faz um reload da pagina toda realmente perde tudo, o jeito seria algo como o localstorage mesmo, mas talvez voce se interesse mais pelo [session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage), que é a mesma coisa, mas ao contrario do locastorage os dados são apagados assim que o navegador fecha.

Comment: Mais se eu usar service ele não vai armazenar o objeto json quando eu voltar do brower pois o mesmo será recarregado, pois eu não possuo um header stático com páginas sendo abertas por dentro.
No meu caso o single page é carregado mais como um todo